# Should I choose to use database for a shopping Android application

Tags: java, android, database

I'm building an Android application which reads all information lists for locations, restaurants and foods. For example:

> **locations**: A, B, C, etc.
>
> A has **restaurants**: a, b, c
>
> a has **foods**: x, y, z

In server side, database is created to transfer JSON object to Android application.

> - MainActivity:
>
>   - PickFood Fragment (select restaurant to enter FoodActivity, display **locations** and **restaurants**)
>   - ShoppingCart Fragment (display **selected foods**)
>   - UserProfile Fragment
> - FoodActivity (display **foods**)

My current solution is to create instances using Java class to display items for different items (e.g. locations or foods) required by activities or fragments. Is this a good solution? Or should I use database to store it since I find it's not convenient to pass selected instances to shopping cart?

Comment: In my idea having database or not has both advantages and disadvantages. The most important advantage is supporting offline services but the biggest disadvantage is updating and retrieving data from db. But in my experience advantages of having db is more than not having it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create model classes which will hold data for location, food etc. You can map JSON to these classes by parsing JSON (you can use library like gson etc).

After mapping, you have three choices:

1. Use model classes directly to consume data in activities or fragments
2. Save the data to db and then display it (if you want to use ORM tools than have a look at [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)) Here, you will have to sync data with local db if there happens any change in server data
3. You can use libraries like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), which can parse json, load model classes, and it can also cache json, so that you can access local data if you are offline.

Any option you select, should be according to your need

Comment: Thanks polerface. Following by your answer, I review the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library but it's hard for me to understand it. Then, I decide to use volley and gson library for now, and consume data in activities or fragments.